# javascript and <option>

Tags: javascript, html

I do have the following JavaScript.

```
<form>  
<select id="sel">
    <option value="1">item_1</option>
    <option value="2">item_2</option>
    <option value="3">item_3</option>
</select>
<div id="show"></div>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
var sel = document.getElementById('sel');
sel.onchange = function() {
  var show = document.getElementById('show');
  show.innerHTML = this.value;
};
</script>
```

If I click onchange a new value (here: 1,2, or 3) is shown in the div "show". This is working fine. But my problem is that I want a different value to be shown but the value (1,2, or 3) should be submitted. The item has a unit like kg, pound, m, m², ....

I want something like that:

```
<option value="1" value2="kg">item_1</option>
```

I changed `value` to `value2` in `<script>` but it didn't help.

```
show.innerHTML = this.value2;
```

How can I get it to work?

Comment: FYI - this is not jQuery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you apply what @Simon said, you can try the following:

```
sel.onchange = function() {
   var show = document.getElementById('show');
   show.innerHTML = this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('value2');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Revised HTML:

```
<form>  
    <select id="sel">
        <option value="1" data-unit="kg">item_1</option>
        <option value="2" data-unit="kph">item_2</option>
        <option value="3" data-unit="m2">item_3</option>
    </select>
</form>

<div id="show"></div>
```

The revised HTML uses the custom, and in HTML5 *valid*, `data-*` attribute to store the units. I've also moved the `div` out of the `form`, but that's an entirely personal inclination, and one that you don't have to maintain (obviously...).

Amended JavaScript:

```
var sel = document.getElementById('sel');
sel.onchange = function() {
    var show = document.getElementById('show');
    show.innerHTML = this.value + this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-unit');
};
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/U9DuN/1/).

The JavaScript looks for the option within the `this` node with the `selectedIndex`, and then uses `getAttribute()` to find the string contained within the `data-unit` attribute and concatenates that to the `this.value` string.

Comment: This is working! But with this.value the value is still submitted! If this.value isn't in the code, it is working fine. Take a look @diaho Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

That should probably be:

```
show.innerHTML = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
```

Comment: No. If you look closely, his `this.value` statement is contained within a closure. This changes the scope of the `this` object.

Answer (score 0):

If the list is not a dynamically generated one, why don't you use an "if else" construct or a "switch" construct on the populated values and display whatever you like?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `value` attribute for the value you want submitted to the server since `value` is meant to contain a string that is meant to be interpreted by a computer as part of a form.

Use a different attribute to associate human readable text with the `<option>`.  `title` and `longdesc` would be good choices.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using jQuery if you can. If you're expecting to be able to use html5 compliant browsers, you can use the data attributes on your `<option>` elements. This way you'd be able to store whatever attributes you found useful.

[jQuery data attributes usage](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use .innerHTML instead of .value if you want to display the text from the drop down. If you want something completely different to be displayed, you'll need a lookup table or something similar - might be easier to use jQuery.